# How do I vertically align a div at a specific spot with other elements having different heights? html/css

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble for a while trying to align elements starting at a specific moment going downward, and being responsive to different element height.

I want it to use display flex. It needs to adjust/decrease columns as a window resizes.
thanks a ton

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHC7f.png)

Comment: Please include the code you have tried and explain more what your HTML structure is.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```css
.container {
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #DDDDDD;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 550px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.item {
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  height: 200px;
  width: 26%;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.item:nth-child(1) {
  height: 150px;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  height: 200px;
}

.item:nth-child(3), .item:nth-child(5) {
  height: 300px;
}

.item:nth-child(4), .item:nth-child(6) {
  height: 160px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The grid style you need is called 'Masonry Layout'. You will get many ready to use cdn on the web. Just embed a cdn in the script tag inside the head tag. And it would do the magic.
I am providing a sample code for you down here.

```css
  .image {
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
     }
  #image1{
    height: 550px;
  }
  #image2{
    height: 350px;
  }
  #image3{
    height: 450px;
  }
  #image4{
    height: 550px;
  }
  #image5{
    height: 250px;
  }
  #image6{
    height: 450px;
  }
  #image7{
    height: 450px;
  }
  #image8{
    height: 450px;
  }
  #image9{
    height: 550px;
  }
  #image10{
    height: 250px;
  }
  #image11{
    height: 250px;
  }
  #image12{
    height: 250px;
  }

@media only screen and (max-width:992px) {
    .image{
        height:400px;
    }
    
}
@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
    .image{
        height:300px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width:576px) {
    #image1{
        height:250px;
    }
    #image2{
        height:250px;
    }
    #image3{
        height:250px;
    }
    #image4{
        height:250px;
    }
    #image5{
        height:250px;
    }
    #image6{
        height:250px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!--Masonry Layout cdn-->
  <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/masonry-layout@4.2.2/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-GNFwBvfVxBkLMJpYMOABq3c+d3KnQxudP/mGPkzpZSTYykLBNsZEnG2D9G/X/+7D" crossorigin="anonymous"
    async></script>
</head>

<body>

  <section >
    <div class="container">     
      <div class="row g-3" data-masonry='{"percentPosition": true }'>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 ">
            <img class="image" id="image1" src="https://i.ibb.co/YNvbbMC/0V5A0971.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12">
            <img class="image" id="image2" src="https://i.ibb.co/YpZ3NBH/0V5A0975.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12">
            <img class="image" id="image3" src="https://i.ibb.co/pxVtdR9/0V5A0980.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12">
            <img class="image" id="image4" src="https://i.ibb.co/CWTXksK/0V5A2619.jpg" >
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12">
            <img class="image" id="image5" src="https://i.ibb.co/LJdmcdc/0V5A2620.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12">
            <img class="image" id="image6" src="https://i.ibb.co/XxMVkDX/0V5A2621.jpg">
        </div>       
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Click on 'Full page' and adjust the window to see it's responsive behaviour.

Let me explain the code.

- HTML snippet

Masonry cdn is embedded inside the head. I have used [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/) here. It would work even with regular CSS. But Bootstrap makes life easy. Class 'image' is common to all the images and each one is having its own id.

- CSS snippet

Applying width 100% and object-fit=cover to all the images so that they don't overflow. Next, I have mentioned the default heights of images followed by how much should their height be as the window width changes.

Comment: Didn't mentioned Bootstrap, only HTML & CSS.

Comment: @MeghnaBhuptani It would work without Bootstrap too.  It's just that bootstrap has the responsive behavior inbuilt into it. So I used it for simplicity

Comment: Yes, but they only require HTML & CSS. If they want than they add Boostrap tag in question.